# jquery auto scroll website with pause

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I set jQuery auto scroll web page and with pause / stop for a specific px and continue auto scrolling? It's something like a user scrolling on the web page reading an article, like scroll and stop and continue scrolling something like that. I can't seem to find a good example on the internet and all I got the answer from searching is only jQuery auto scroll example only.

If you can't understand my question it's something looks like this: [Example from codepen](https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/PzGBJx?editors=0010)

Here is my code:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);

setTimeout(function() {
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 1000); // 1000 is the duration of the animation
},500);

setInterval(function(){

$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 500); //  Speed from Bottom to top

setTimeout(function() {
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 5000); // Speed from Top to bottom
},500); // What is this speed refer to?

},1000); // What is this speed refer to?
```

By the way, I am new in jQuery, do you mind explain a little bit to me what is the meaning of both of the 500 and 1000 second meaning? I know it refers to second but what is the meaning of adding 2 of it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is an working example**

```js
setInterval(function scroll() {
  $("section").each(function(i, e) {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $(e).offset().top
    }, 500).delay(500); // First value is a speed of scroll, and second time break
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 5000); // This is the speed of scroll up
  }, 4000); //This means after what time should it begin (after scrolling ends)
  return scroll;
}(), 9000); //This value means after what time should the function be triggered again
//(It should be sum of all animation time and delay) 9000 = 5000 + 4000
```

```css
main {
  background: #EEE;
}

main section {
  background: #DDD;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  min-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main>
  <section>
  </section>
  <section>
  </section>
  <section>
  </section>
  <section>
  </section>
</main>
```

**EDIT**

I edited a little bit snippet so that the code was not twice. I declare function (`scroll()`) and use it inside interval. Thanks to that there is no need for the same code at the begining.

**EDIT2**

If you want the scroll to stop depending on px and not section just change this:

```js
setInterval(function scroll() {
  $("section").each(function(i, e) {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $(e).offset().top
    }, 500).delay(500); // First value is a speed of scroll, and second time break
  });
  ...
```

To this:

```js
setInterval(function scroll() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4000; i += 800) {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: i
    }, 500).delay(500);
  }
  ...
```

**EDIT3**

If you want to scroll to bottom at the end, you can do it like this:

```js
setInterval(function scroll() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4000; i += 800) {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: i
    }, 500).delay(500);
    if (i + 800 >= 4000) {
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(document).height()
      }, 500).delay(500);
    }
  }
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the amazing explanation and you really teaching me a lot! Appreciate it! As yesterday I can't find a similar example what I'm trying to achieve. As the old example is more likely to pause section by section but the more accurate example is like this: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Automatic-Smooth-Page-Scroll-Plugin-With-jQuery-verticalScroller-js/ I've tried to modify the answer you've given me but I can't make it as pause like a new example. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Ace what is the difference between https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Automatic-Smooth-Page-Scroll-Plugin-With-jQuery-verticalScroller-js/ and the one I wrote? What would you like to happen differently?

Comment: So basically the difference between the example form codepen is that one is to pause according to the section, and the new example is more likely to pause at a certain px/height I think. :) That's what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Last question, how can I make it go down to the html body bottom and repeat it the same again from scrolling bottom to top? I've been trying but can't figure it out...

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to helping me so much, I really learn a lot from you! :)